# Can't run multiple ngrok tunnels using config file

Tags: ngrok, tunneling

I would like to run multiple Ngrok subdomains

I have created an ngrok.yml file

```
tunnels:
  teams:
    proto: http
    addr: 8000
    subdomain: expl
  jira:
    proto: http
    addr: 8080
    subdomain: expl2
```

Then I run `./ngrok start teams -config=ngrok.yml`

I have a Basic plan I have already registres my authtoken.

But I get this message

Only paid plans may bind custom subdomains.

> Failed to bind the custom subdomain 'explore' for an
> unauthenticated client. Sign up at: https://dashboard.ngrok.com/signup
>
> If you have already signed up, make sure your authtoken is installed.
> Your authtoken is available on your dashboard:
> https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken
>
> ERR_NGROK_305

But I'm able to run a single subdomain tunnel using command :
`./ngrok http -hostname=exple 3000`, it works

Comment: Suggestion: Try https://pinggy.io , much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you double check that you have included your `authtoken: <TOKEN>` at the top of your new config? That would explain why the single command works (because it is using the original config with the authtoken) but the command pointing to a new config does not.

Answer (score 0):

Config file `ngrok.yml`:

```
version: "2"
authtoken: *put your key here*
region: eu *#or what you want*
tunnels:
    web:
        proto: http
        addr: 80
        inspect: false
    tcp1:
        proto: tcp
        addr: 3306
    tcp2:
        proto: tcp
        addr: 4000
```

Works if you start with:

```
ngrok start --all --config ./ngrok.yml
```